# Set item opacity in RecyclerView depending if item is in center

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-animation

I want to display items in a horizontal list using `RecyclerView`. At a time, only 3 items will be displayed. 1 in the middle and the other 2 on the side, below is an image of what I'm trying to achieve:

[image]

I'm using `LinearSnapHelper` which centers an item all of the time. When an item is moved away from the center I would like the opacity to progessively change from `1f` to `0.5f`.

Here is the below code which I've written to help:

```
class CustomRecyclerView(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet) : RecyclerView(context, attrs) {
    
    private var itemBoundsRect: Rect? = null

    init {
        itemBoundsRect = Rect()
        addOnScrollListener(object : OnScrollListener() {
            override fun onScrolled(recyclerView: RecyclerView, dx: Int, dy: Int) {
                super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy)
                calculateVisibility()
            }
        })
    }

    private fun calculateVisibility() {
        val linearLayoutManger: LinearLayoutManager = layoutManager as LinearLayoutManager
        val firstVisibleItem = linearLayoutManger.findFirstVisibleItemPosition()
        val lastVisibleItem = linearLayoutManger.findLastVisibleItemPosition()
        var indexes: MutableList<Int> = mutableListOf()
        for (i in firstVisibleItem..lastVisibleItem) {
            indexes.add(i)
            val item: View = layoutManager?.findViewByPosition(i) ?: continue
            item.getGlobalVisibleRect(itemBoundsRect)
            var itemSize = layoutManager!!.findViewByPosition(i)!!.width
            
            var visibleSize = 0
            if (indexes.size == 1) {
                visibleSize = itemBoundsRect!!.right
            } else {
                visibleSize = itemBoundsRect!!.right - itemBoundsRect!!.left
            }



            var visibilty = visibleSize * 100 / itemSize
            if (visibilty > 0) {
                visibilty = 100 - visibilty
            }

            val viewHolder = findViewHolderForLayoutPosition(i)
            viewHolder!!.itemView.alpha = (100 - visibilty).toFloat() / 100f
        }
    }
}
```

It doesn't work as expected as the opacity changes at the wrong time. The image below demonstrates this better. I expect the opacity to progressively begin to change when the item edges come out of the red box. However, it only starts when the item reaches the yellow edges.

[image]

Is there a way to achieve this effect?

Thank you :)

Comment: You don't say what doesn't work as expected. Do you know that `calculateVisibility()` is being called? Is it being called, but the opacity doesn't change? Is that the problem?

Comment: @Cheticamp Apologies, I've updated the question to show it's current behavior and what is expected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code for `calculateVisibility()` is looking at global position when looking at the relative position within the *RecyclerView* is sufficient. Maybe there is more to the code than you posted, but try the following. This code looks at the `x` position of each visible view and calculates the alpha value as a function of displacement from the center of the *RecyclerView*. Comments are in the code.

```
private fun calculateVisibility(recycler: RecyclerView) {
    val midRecycler = recycler.width / 2
    val linearLayoutManger: LinearLayoutManager = recycler.layoutManager as LinearLayoutManager
    val firstVisibleItem = linearLayoutManger.findFirstVisibleItemPosition()
    val lastVisibleItem = linearLayoutManger.findLastVisibleItemPosition()
    for (i in firstVisibleItem..lastVisibleItem) {
        val viewHolder = recycler.findViewHolderForLayoutPosition(i)
        viewHolder?.itemView?.apply {
            // This is the end of the view in the parent's coordinates
            val viewEnd = x + width
            // This is the maximum pixels the view can slide left or right until it disappears.
            val maxSlide = (midRecycler + width / 2).toFloat()
            // Alpha is determined by the percentage of the maximum slide the view has moved.
            // This assumes a linear fade but can be adjusted to fade in alternate ways.
            alpha = 1f - abs(maxSlide - viewEnd) / maxSlide
            Log.d("Applog", String.format("pos=%d alpha=%f", i, alpha))
        }
    }
}
```

The foregoing assumes that sizes remain constant.

Answer (score -1):

if you need the center View, you can call

```
 View view =  snapHelper.findSnapView(layoutManagaer);
```

once you have the View, you should be able to get the position on the dataset for that View. For instance using

```
int pos = adapter.getChildAdapterPosition(view)
```

And then you can update the center View opacity and invoke

```
adapter.notifyItemChanged(pos);
```